# JSP page && tomcat 9 : browser only displays the source code

Tags: spring, jsp, jndi

My browser display jsp code if I run Tomcat 9.

In my pom.xml I add all dependencies for servlet and jstl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
             https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>ml.kalanblow</groupId>
                <artifactId>kalanblow</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <name>kalanblow</name>
                <description>Kalanblow project for Spring</description>
                <packaging>war</packaging>
                <properties>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                    <spring.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
                    <hibernate.version>5.4.12.Final</hibernate.version>
                    <hibernate.validator>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.validator>
                    <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
                    <tld.version>1.1.2</tld.version>
                    <servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
                    <jsp.version>2.3.3</jsp.version>
                    <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
                    <mail.version>1.6.1</mail.version>
                    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
                    <spring-data-jpa.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
                    <postgresql-version>42.2.8</postgresql-version>
                </properties>
                <reporting>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </reporting>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Spring core -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Spring AOP -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Spring ORM -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Security -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Spring jpa -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Spring context -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Hibernate Core -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                        <version>${tld.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${servlets.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- JSP Dependency -->
                    <!-- JSP API -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- servlet-api -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- HSQL Dependency -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                        <version>${mail.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.0-alpha0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Test -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <build>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.5.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </project>
```

A new JSP project was created ,after the start of the tomcat, the browser only displays the source code.

Initially, the jsp file and associated java classes were built and tested fine on a test Tomcat server. Now, they've been transitioned to another server of what I believe is the same setup (except it's linux now instead of windows). But when the jsp page is accessed the source code is displayed instead of the jsp actually executing. I've googled for a while but received no success.

Comment: Have you checked the response header? Is it going to Tomcat Apache or not?

Comment: Hello, the response Header goint to Tomcat. This is one solution:My jsp page opens on the Internet on a Windows machine, but it doesn't open on Chrome and Firefox. Since I'm working on a linux machine, I'm going to install IE by following this tutorial before finding another alternative. This is the link: http://blog.bruyere-freelance.fr/installer-internet-explorer-ie-9-10-11-edge-sur-linux-ubuntu-16-04/